# call from one stored procedure that returns result set to another stored procedure for combining that result set

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that gives one input parameter. It compares the values of two colmns in the same table and show if it is 'available' or 'not available'. It returns all the rows (30) of that table as result set. When I run it, it is like

```
1   available
2   available
3   not available
4   not available
5   not available
6   available
7   not available
8   not available
9   available
10  available
11  available
12  not available
```

But I would like to pair 1 and 2, and then 3 and 4. Then show 'available' or 'not available' using OR operator. Let's suppose if 1 is 'available' and 2 is 'available' , then show it like 'available'. Only both values of that pair is available, then show it as 'not available'. How will I write another stored procedure using the result set of the above stored procedure. Right now the result set from this stored procedure is 30 rows, but I want to get 15 result set by paring 1 and 2, 3 and 4, and so on. I think I have to call one stored procedure to another procedure but how will I compare those results in second stored procedure.
Thank you.

Comment: "Only both values of that pair is available, then show it as 'not available'." -> you want to show 'not available' if both values are 'available', or am I reading it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- Declare a table variable that captures
-- the output from your SP
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  A varchar(15)
)

-- Add rows from SP to @T
insert into @T
exec GetValues

-- Query the table variable
select T1.ID as ID1,
       T2.ID as ID2,
       case when 'available' in (T1.A, T2.A)
            then 'available' 
            else 'not available'
       end as A 
from @T as T1
  inner join @T as T2
    on T1.ID + 1 = T2.ID
where T1.ID % 2 = 1
```

Result with your test data:

```
ID1         ID2         A
----------- ----------- -------------
1           2           available
3           4           not available
5           6           available
7           8           not available
9           10          available
11          12          available
```

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[check] 
 @Type int
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here 

     IF @Type= 1
     BEGIN
     SELECT
 CASE WHEN TOneOccupy < TOne 
 THEN 'Avail'
 ELSE 'Not Avail' 
 END
 FROM tb
 END
 
 ELSE IF @Type= 2
 BEGIN
 SELECT
 CASE WHEN TTwoOccupy < TTwo 
 THEN  'Avail'
 ELSE 'Not Avail' 
 END
 FROM tb
 END
 
 ELSE IF @Type= 3
 BEGIN
 SELECT
 CASE WHEN TThreeOccupy < TThree 
 THEN  'Avail'
 ELSE 'Not Avail' 
 END
 FROM tb
 END
 
 
END

Comment: I tried my sp with your code but I can only run my first sp, not the second sp that is your code. plz have a look at my sp and how will i update second sp & execute it. thz u so much.